# Prove $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$ converges $\iff$ $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ln (b_n)$ converges.

Tags: infinite-product

Okay, so I'm stuck on this question which is part (b) to the question and was wondering if someone could help me out with it, I have solved the first part as seen below, (would you also be able to check (a); I feel my communication is lacking as the proof is very small), thanks!

**Question**

Consider a sequence $(b_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ of non-zero real numbers. By definition, the infinite product $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges if the sequence $(p_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$, where

$p_n=\prod_{k=1}^{n}b_k$

converges to some non-zero number.

**(a)** Prove that the convergence of $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$ implies $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=1$

**Working (a)**

If $p_n \rightarrow p\neq 0$,

then $b_n=\frac{p_n}{p_{n-1}}=\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{n}b_k}{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}b_k}\rightarrow\frac{p}{p}=1$

QED

**(b)** Assume $b_n>0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Prove that $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$ converge if and only if

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ln (b_n)$

converges. (You may use without proof the fact that $\ln(x)$ is a continuous function on $(0, \infty)$.)

Thanks again :)

Comment: Suggestion: Use the fact that the function $ln $ is continous and it's inverse $x\to e^x $ is continuous.

Comment: Part **b)** is a duplicate of [How to approach this proof on convergence of infinite product?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2291850/how-to-approach-this-proof-on-convergence-of-infinite-product/2292878). Part **a)** is a duplicate of [Prove that the convergence of $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$ implies $\lim_{n→∞} b_n = 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2303595/prove-that-the-convergence-of-prod-n-1-infty-b-n-implies-lim-n%e2%86%92%e2%88%9e-b-n). Please stick to one question per post.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that $\log (xy)=\log x+\log y$. For you question, you have
$$\log\left(\lim_{N\to \infty} \prod_{n=1}^N b_n\right)=\lim_{N\to \infty}\log\prod_{n=1}^N b_n=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N \log b_n$$
and you can interchange the limit and the logarithm because $\log$ is a continuous function on $(0,\infty)$. Here, you use your hypotheses on $b_n$. Then, the convergence of one side is dependant on the convergence of the other and vice versa.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this does help a lot, I was wondering if you were able to check my part (a), thanks!