# Is this proof for infinte product in complex analysis correct

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, infinite-product

I am doing some assignments of an institute in which I dont study in complex analysis .

I am looking for verification of following proof and if its incorrect kindly give correct proof .

> Prove that $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} z_n $ converges if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} log(z_n)$ converges.

Attempt :$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} z_n $ converges to k  iff $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} log(z_n)$ converges to log k   .

Is it fine ?

Comment: Your attempt is a statement that's even stronger than what you're trying to prove, but you haven't justified it. What is your reasoning?

Comment: What is the definition of $\log(z_n)$?

Comment: The statement is not true. What if $z_n = \frac{1}{n}$ ?

Comment: If $z_n=1/n$ the infinite product **diverges** to zero.

Comment: @AnginaSeng why is that considered a divergence? The sequence of partial products $p_n = \frac{1}{n!}$ converges to zero like a usual sequence.

Comment: @NinadMunshi See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product This case is considered as a divergence case.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe okay, sounds good to me

Comment: in the theory of infinite products one considers $p_{m,n}=\prod_{k=m}^{n} z_k, n \ge m$ and calls the product convergent when there is an index $m_0$ st $p_{n,m_0} \to z_{m_0}^* \ne 0, n \to \infty$ and then the value of the product is $z_1...z_{m_0-1}z_{m_0}^*$ this is to allow products that are zero but disallow convergence to zero which is considered divergence; this is very well adapted to products of holomorphic functions which then, if converge, have zeroes precisely at the zeroes of the factors, so one can build the classic Weierstrass/Hadamard factorization theory

Comment: So , the question in assignment was wrong .

Comment: @Théophile Can you please tell what stronger assertion I made ?, It would be really helpful for me.

Comment: @Ben The question asks you to prove a general statement about convergence; your stronger statement (that you claimed, but did not prove) is about convergence to a particular value. It is stronger in the sense that it is more specific. Imagine this: "Prove that the earth is not flat. Attempt: the earth, in fact, is a giant doughnut." The "attempt" here is a stronger statement than what was asked for, but isn't a proof, just a claim.

Comment: @Ben Also, to be clear, the question is not wrong. Ninad Munshi was mistaken regarding the definition of convergence. See the Wikipedia link above on Infinite products.

Comment: @Theophile Ok, got it. Can you please tell how to prove it?

Comment: @Ben Perhaps this will help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2291850/how-to-approach-this-proof-on-convergence-of-infinite-product

Comment: @Théophile thanks for help!!

Comment: You're welcome!